# Laws of fuzzy logic

Tags: fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

I need help to prove the following equality in fuzzy logic. Proof that $A\cup A^c=U$ where $U$ represents a classic set, but is valid considering the T-norm drastic $T_D=${$a$ if $b=1$ , $b$ if $a=1$ or $0$ otherwise)

If $\varphi_A$ is the pertinency function of $A$. I did

In classical logical sets,$A\cup A^c = U$ where $U$ represents the universal set, but em logical fuzzy this is not true in general, but is true when you consider the Drastic T-norm. If you have two  fuzzy sets $A$ and $B$ and a classical set $U$ knowing that $\varphi_A(x) \in [0,1]$ and $\varphi_B(x) \in [0,1]$ where $\varphi_A$ and $\varphi_B$ is the degree to which the x element belongs U. Now suppose we take the element $x=3 \in U$ and $\varphi_A(3)=0.4$ and $\varphi_B(3)=1$ then by the Drastic T-norm we have that $T_D(a,b)=0.4$ because $b=1$

Comment: Can you explain the conditions in a little bit more detail? What do you exactly mean by $A\cup A^c=U$ '*considering the $T$-norm drastic$\dots$*'?

Comment: take a look again @Berci

Comment: Ok. But.. don't we have any assumption on $A$? Or.. how do you mean $A\cup A^c=U$ when considering the $T_D$-norm? How could a whatever norm effect complement and union of (fuzzy) sets?

Answer (score 0):

In general, $A\cup A^c\neq U$. This is caused by the definition of a complement of a fuzzy set: $A^c(x)=1-A(x)$
This is, the degree of $x$ on the fuzzy set $A^c$ is $1-$ the degree of $x$ on the fuzzy set $A$. Since the degree of every $x\in U$ is $1$, we conclude that $A\cup A^c\neq U$ taking $A(x)$ between 0 than 1 (not inclusive).